# Format the content of the file using Perl

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a file with the following format:

```
>Country1 
Aus
trali
a

>Country5
Swi
tzer
land

>Country2
Net
herland
s
```

I want to output a file with the following format:

```
>Country1 Australia
>Country5 Switzerland
>Country2 Netherlands
```

Comment: What determines the places where you want a line break: where the input contains an empty line, or before `>`?

Answer (score 8):

A straight `Perl` solution:

```
$ perl -lne '
    if(/^>/) {printf "%s ", $_;next}
    if(/^$/) {printf "\n";next}
    printf "%s", $_;
' file
>Country1 Australia
>Country5 Switzerland
>Country2 Netherlands
```

or a shorter way:

```
$ perl -ane 'BEGIN{$/="";};print "$F[0] ",@F[1..$#F],"\n"' file
>Country1 Australia
>Country5 Switzerland
>Country2 Netherlands
```

Set `$/` to empty string causes Perl switch into paragraph mode, meaning record separator is one or more blank lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`-p` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-p*) to process the file line by line and output each processed line. Replace the newline by a space if the line starts with `>`, and by nothing if it starts by another non-newline character (i.e. if it isn't empty).

```
perl -pe 'if (/^>/) {s/\n/ /} elsif (/^./) {s/\n//}'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -ne 'print "$_ " if m/^\>/; .print if m/<alpha>+ $/; .put unless .chars;'
```

Sample Input:

```
>Country1
Aus
trali
a

>Country5
Swi
tzer
land

>Country2
Net
herland
s
```

Sample Output:

```
>Country1 Australia
>Country5 Switzerland
>Country2 Netherlands
```

Kudos to @Gilles, who was able to do this in Perl in a single if/else statement. The code above uses three Raku statements, exploiting the difference between `print` and `put`. In Raku, `print` doesn't add a newline terminator, while `put` does. Also, in Raku the `~` tilde is used for string-concatenation, thus the interpolated `"$_ "` could have been written `$_~" "`.

A (possible?) advantage of Raku for cognate problems is rigorous Unicode implementation of the `chars` routine (NFG Normalization). See URLs at bottom.

https://6guts.wordpress.com/2015/04/12/this-week-unicode-normalization-many-rts/
https://docs.raku.org/routine/chars
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

If there are no tabs within your input lines you could use this method:

```
$ awk NF infile | awk '{$1=$1};1' | paste - - - - | sed 's/ //2g'
>Country1 Australia
>Country5 Switzerland
>Country2 Netherlands
```

The first awk removes blank lines. The second awk trims leading/trailing spaces.
Paste command (with four hyphens) merges every four lines separated by a tab. And finally sed removes unwanted tabs. Replace the first tab by a space if you wish.